# How do I get an event using fullcalendar getEventSourceById?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

The function as mentioned [in the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEventSourceById) doesn't seem to be working:

- Events are added with ids 1 and 2.
- I execute `calendar.getEventSourceById(1)`
- I expect to get the first event

To reproduce see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/full-calendar-demo-forked-iihhvn

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). CodeSandbox can be useful but for your question to be on-topic here you must provide enough relevant code here as well. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, try `calendar.addEventSource({ id: 1, events: events });`. You didn't give the event source an ID, so you can't expect to retrieve it by a nonexistent ID. Fullcalendar doesn't automatically assign one (it may assign one for its own internal use, but it's not exposed through the API).

Comment: @ADyson I've cleaned up the code a bit so only the basics remain. Events are added during initialisation (with ids), it should work imho.

Comment: `Events are added during initialisation (with ids)`...yes, but `getEventSourceById` is supposed to fetch an _event source_ object, not individual events within it. Maybe you confused this with [getEventById](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEventById)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I should have used

```
calendar.getEventById(1)
```

and not

```
calendar.getEventSourceById(1)
```